# Sum of Boolean Operators on Numpy Bool Arrays (Bug?)

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, boolean-operations

I've come across a surprising situation when using `numpy`'s `array`s. The following code

```
(True==True)+(True==True)
```

returns `2`, as one would expect. While

```
import numpy
Array=numpy.zeros((2,2),dtype=bool)
(Array[0][0]==Array[0][0])+(Array[1][0]==Array[1][0])
```

returns `True`. This leads to:

```
(Array[0][0]==Array[0][0])+(Array[1][0]==Array[1][0])-1
```

returning `0`, while

```
(Array[0][0]==Array[0][0])-1+(Array[1][0]==Array[1][0])
```

returns `1`, making the sum not commutative!

Is this intended? If so, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that `numpy.bool_` behaves slightly differently to vanilla Python `bool`:

```
>>> int(True+True) == int(True) + int(True)
True
>>> int(numpy.bool_(1)+numpy.bool_(1)) == int(numpy.bool_(1)) + int(numpy.bool_(1))
False
```

This is because:

```
>>> True+True
2
>>> numpy.bool_(1)+numpy.bool_(1)
True
>>> int(numpy.bool_(1)+numpy.bool_(1))
1
```

Basically, the addition operation for `numpy.bool_` is logical, rather than numerical; to get the same behaviour with `bool`:

```
>>> int(True and True)
1
```

This is fine if you only use it for truthiness, as intended, but if you try to use it in an integer context without being explicit about that, you end up surprised. As soon as you're explicit, expected behaviour is restored:

```
>>> int(numpy.bool_(1)) + int(numpy.bool_(1))
2
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a reason why numpys bool was designed to behave different than vanillas bool? Or wasn't the sum of bools intended in vanillas bool either?
Maybe no one had given it a thought ^^

Comment: I don't, no. There is some discussion about removing these operators [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion%40scipy.org/msg43366.html), if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this motivated me to write cleaner and prettier Python code. Even more so after seeing all the other issues I hadn't noticed (and probably would never notice).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is th autocasting.

in this case:

```
(Array[0][0]==Array[0][0])+(Array[1][0]==Array[1][0])-1
Python do:
(Array[0][0]==Array[0][0])+(Array[1][0]==Array[1][0]) = True
True -1 =cast= 1 -1 = 0
```

In the second case the cast is do it before:

```
(Array[0][0]==Array[0][0])-1+(Array[1][0]==Array[1][0])
True - 1 + True 
(True - 1 =cast= 0)
0 + True =cast again=  0+ 1 = 1
```

So, it's not a bug. It's a autocasting in diferent parts.